# Getting list of Facebook friends with latest API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-apps, facebook-friends

I'm using [the most recent version of the Facebook SDK](http://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/) (which lets to connect to something called the 'graph API' though I'm not sure). I've adapted Facebook's example code to let me connect to Facebook and that works... but I can't get a list of my friends.

```
$friends = $facebook->api('friends.get');
```

This produces the error message: "Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: friends.get thrown in /mycode/facebook.php on line 543"

No clue why that is or what that means. Can someone tell me the right syntax (for the latest Facebook API) to get a list of friends? (I tried "$friends = $facebook->api->friends_get();" and get a different error, "Fatal error: Call to a member function friends_get() on a non-object in /mycode/example.php on line 129".)

I can confirm that BEFORE this point in my code, things are fine: I'm connected to Facebook with a valid session and I can get my info and dump it to the screen just... i.e. this code executes perfectly before the failed friends.get call:

```
$session = $facebook->getSession();
if ($session) {
    $uid = $facebook->getUser();
    $me = $facebook->api('/me');
}
print_r($me);
```

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
$friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends');
```

Comment: by any chance yo know how to get someone's profile picture with an api call ? something like...    $friends = $facebook->api('/idofosmefriend/picture'); And there is some documentation with all of those calls ?, thanks !

Comment: @nfvs, do you know how i can acccess friends_hometown?

Comment: This no longer works with Graph API v2 or even legacy Graph API v1 apps. See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/friends
"This will only return any friends who have used (via Facebook Login) the app making the request."

Answer (score 23):

This is live version of PHP Code to get your friends from Facebook

```
<?php
    $user = $facebook->getUser();


    if ($user) {
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
        $friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends');

        echo '<ul>';
        foreach ($friends["data"] as $value) {
            echo '<li>';
            echo '<div class="pic">';
            echo '<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/' . $value["id"] . '/picture"/>';
            echo '</div>';
            echo '<div class="picName">'.$value["name"].'</div>'; 
            echo '</li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: The documentation say that, it shows the friends who also use your app. I have tried above code and got that result. See their link: (Check read_friendlists section) https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.2

Answer (score 12):

Getting the friends like @nfvs describes is a good way. It outputs a multi-dimensional array with all friends with attributes id and name (ordered by id). You can see the friends photos like this:

```
foreach ($friends as $key=>$value) {
    echo count($value) . ' Friends';
    echo '<hr />';
    echo '<ul id="friends">';
    foreach ($value as $fkey=>$fvalue) {
        echo '<li><img src="https://graph.facebook.com/' . $fvalue->id . '/picture" title="' . $fvalue->name . '"/></li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

Comment: worked! thanks, just one line threw an error for me....in the second foreach loop... i changed it to the following so it worked for me, echo '<li><img src="https://graph.facebook.com/' . $fvalue->id . '/picture" title="' . $fvalue->name . '"/></li>';

Comment: it working as per your suggestion and same updated in the code. thanks Stevanicus & Geoffa

Answer (score 7):

Just a heads up for anyone stumbling across this question using v2.0 of the Graph API: This will not work anymore. In v2.0, calling /me/friends only returns a list the person's friends who *also use the app*:

> - A user access token with user_friends permission is required to view the current person's friends.
> - This will only return any friends who have used (via Facebook Login) the app making the request.
> - If a friend of the person declines the user_friends permission, that friend will not show up in the friend list for this person.

Comment: Is there any way to get a list of all friends with the 2.0 Graph API?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use the REST end point,

```
$friends = $facebook->api(array('method' => 'friends.get'));
```

else if you are using the graph api, then use,

```
$friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends');
```

Answer (score 3):

in the recent version of facebook sdk , facebook has disabled the feature that let you access some one friends list due to security reasons ... check the documentation to learn more ...

Answer (score 2):

Use FQL instead, its a like SQL but for Facebook's data tables and easily covers data query you'de like to make.
You won't have to use all of those /xx/xxx/xx calls, just know the tables and columns you are intereseted in.

```
$myQuery = "SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me()";
$facebook->api( "/fql?q=" . urlencode($myQuery) )
```

Great interactive examples at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/

Answer (score 0):

> Using CodeIgniter OAuth2/0.4.0 sparks,
>
> in Auth.php file,

```
$user = $provider->get_user_info($token);

$friends = $provider->get_friends_list($token);
print_r($friends);
```

> and in Facebook.php file under Provider, add the following function,

```
    public function get_friends_list(OAuth2_Token_Access $token)
    {
            $url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?'.http_build_query(array(
                    'access_token' => $token->access_token,
            ));
            $friends = json_decode(file_get_contents($url),TRUE);

            return $friends;
    }

prints the facebenter code hereook friends.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
friends.get
```

Is function to get a list of friend's

And yes this is best

```
    $friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends');

    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($friends["data"] as $value) {
        echo '<li>';
        echo '<div class="pic">';
        echo '<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/' . $value["id"] . '/picture"/>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<div class="picName">'.$value["name"].'</div>'; 
        echo '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
```

Answer (score 0):

[https://graph.facebook.com/v1.0/me/friends?limit=${limit}&access_token=${accessToken}](https://graph.facebook.com/v1.0/me/friends?limit=$%7Blimit%7D&access_token=$%7BaccessToken%7D)

this api worked for me
try this

Answer (score -3):

header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

input in your page.