# Getting friends list using facebook api's

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I have the following command which will allow me to post a message on the logged in users facebook wall:

```
$facebook->api("/$uid/feed", "POST",  array('message' => 'Hello! I\'m using the FB Graph API!'));
```

i.e. using the url `https://graph.facebook.com/<user id goes here>/feed`

But what command do I need to enter to get a list of the logged in users friends?

The url I need to use is `https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends`, but I am not sure how to edit the below command to get the friends list:

```
$facebook->api("/$uid/feed", "POST",  array('message' => 'Hello! I\'m using the FB Graph API!'));
```

am I supposed to do something like this (which is a complete guess)

```
$facebook->api("/$uid/friends", "GET",  array('access_token' => 'token value goes here'));
```

Or am I supposed to do something else to get the friends list?

Comment: I'll have to try it tomorrow, run out of time today.  I didn't try it at the time, because it just came into my mind was I was typing the question.  But as far as I can tell, that is not the way to do it.

Comment: Well, I suppose it should work. But anyway, if you have a valid session..something like `$facebook->api("/me/friends")` would work just fine too.

Comment: Yes, that is what I saw, but have not had a chance to try it out.  WIll try tomorrow, the get and acces token this is apparently not needed in teh command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a valid session, then this should retrieve the current user's friends:

```
$friends = $facebook->api("/me/friends")
```

---

<strike>But if you don't have a valid session (or need to retrieve this offline) you need the `offline_access` permission and your code will also work.</strike>
**UPDATE:**
Since the deprication of the `offline_access` permission, you need a [long-lived `access_token`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8982025/how-to-extend-access-token-validity-since-offline-access-deprecation).

---

Please note that you can get the friends list with this FQL query too:

```
$friends = $facebook->api(array(
    "method"    => "fql.query",
    "query"     => "SELECT uid,name FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())"
));
```

Comment: fql queries are about to be deprecated!

Answer (score 2):

This post on SO may provide the answer you are looking for.  You will need to get the friends object then do a foreach loop over it to print the results (as described in the post). Read [Getting list of Facebook friends with latest API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3835028/getting-list-of-facebook-friends-with-latest-api)