# Facebook PHP throwing exception "(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist"

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a valid and authenticated user, but when posting to their wall from our PHP web app it returns:

**Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: xxxxxxxxxxxxx","name":"xxxxxxx**

I have 24 other users that can post with no issues. And I can see the user exists by going to https://graph.facebook.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxx

Here is the code:

```
    $fb_user_id = $row[0]; // loaded from DB
    $facebook_token = $row[1]; // loaded from DB

    $result = $facebook->api('/' . $fb_user_id. '/feed/',
                                'post',
                                array('access_token' => $facebook_token,
                                    'message' => $postMessage,
                                    'name' => 'Product name',
                                    'caption' => 'Accomplished!',
                                    'link' => 'http://www.xxxxxxx.com/',
                                    'description' => $postMessage,
                                    'picture' => 'http://www.xxxxxxx.com/images/productImage.png'));
```

Any ideas why the Facebook API thinks this user does not exist?

Comment: How about sharing your code with us? what fields you are sending with the request?

Comment: Included code - thanks for the prompt.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I had this issue, later I realised I was saving the uid in my database as an `integer`, however, new facebook profiles have very long uids, such as : `100004409446248`, this was not a value I could save as an `integer` in my mysql database, I changed this to treat it as a `varchar`, so now there's no issue

Comment: Why didn't u just use a `BIGINT` instead of a VARCHAR?

Comment: a `BIGINT` would certainly cover the ID above. However, Facebook documentation note the user ID as being "numeric string", other IDs (albums, apps, comments) are documented as being "string", so I would use a string storage rather then a numerical storage. It may be that some IDs have 0 prefixes which would get ignored by using a numeric storage. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/

Comment: This claims an unsigned 64bit is enough, though not official docs.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7138119/saving-facebook-id-as-int-or-varchar

Answer (score 1):

This question [Getting list of Facebook friends with latest API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3835028/getting-list-of-facebook-friends-with-latest-api) suggests

`$friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends');`

Comment: I'm not even trying anything that complicated, just trying to post to a users stream. They have given us publish_stream and offline access.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote two library routine for get integer querystrings. Similar to Dainel's experience when I use the `intval()` function, I get an invalid Facebook id cause produce that error.

Code:

```
function get_int($field) {
    $value = 0;
    if(isset($_GET[$field])) $value = intval($_GET[$field]);
    return $value;
}
```

I use the get_str for facebook_id and problem was gone.

```
function get_str($field) {
    $value = '';
    if(isset($_GET[$field])) $value = $_GET[$field];
    return $value;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Define APP ID as integer, not string!