# Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: 0_309479102458745 thrown in /base_facebook.php on line 1039

My app was working fine and then suddenly many users are gettings this error (with the exception of 0_309479102458745 varying somewhat).

I changed it to treat them as varchar and followed all the suggestions listed here [Facebook PHP throwing exception "(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5892897/facebook-php-throwing-exception-803-some-of-the-aliases-you-requested-do-not).

here is the code causing it:
        $result = $facebook->api('/me/feed/', array('access_token' => $facebook->access_token,'limit'=>50)); //get posts
        foreach($result['data'] as $posts)

I'm not sure exactly where I should begin troubleshooting this since it started out of nowhere.

I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

0_309479102458745  won't work because 0 isn't a valid user ID.

That format of ID is a User or Page ID followed by the post ID; you should never be seeing 0_{post ID} coming back from the feed:

- if you are it could be a bug in the API - you can file it here: https://developers.facebook.com/bug
- if you're manually constructing that value, you may be doing so incorrectly.

Comment: @RobertBlair Have you finally find where does it come from? I meet exactly the same problem. Some times, when parsing the home news feed of a user, I get twice the same post, with one that has a `0_<post-id>` id and the other one that has the good id syntax, ie `<user-id>_<post-id>`.