# FQL call only works from API and not in code

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I've been struggling with this one for a few days. Hopefully someone can help.
I run this FQL query :
SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid IN (SELECT page_id FROM place WHERE
 distance(latitude, longitude, "37.76", "-122.427") < 1000)

Works great using facebooks graph api explorer

Running it in my code gives this error
(OAuthException - #803) (#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid IN (SELECT page_id FROM place WHERE distance(latitude, longitude, "33.675098", "-117.733903") < 1000)
Here is the code

string qry = "SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid IN (SELECT page_id FROM place WHERE distance(latitude, longitude, \"" + lat + "\", \"" + lon + "\") < 1000)";
            var client = new FacebookClient(accessToken);
            dynamic eventIds = client.Get(qry);

Comment: Check this link it can help you somehow. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10168258/fatal-error-uncaught-oauthexception-803-some-of-the-aliases-you-requested-d

Comment: Thanks Furquan, but I've seen that post.  The problem in my case is that it works using the API. It doesn't work when I make the call from my app. its the same call!  Weird