# Importing/Synching Facebook contacts into another application

Tags: php, import, contacts, facebook-php-sdk

I am creating an web-application in PHP, where I would like to synch/import contact information from facebook. I would like to copy the profile picture and name from facebook contacts into my application.

Is there a description/example on how this can be done from an application?

Comment: This is quite a broad question - you should read up about using the [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) and what information you can get from there,  write come code, try it out and if you have errors/problems then come back here and all some more information to your question.  Or alternatively [ask a new question](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting list of Facebook friends with latest API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3835028/getting-list-of-facebook-friends-with-latest-api)

Comment: I know it is broad, but I guess I have to start somewhere. The webapplication I am developing is not a facebook application, but I want to let users connect to facebook and import/synch their facebook contacts into my application. How do users connect to facebook and get access to their contacts?

Comment: I believe this is what I am looking for:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to get info from [`friends`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#friends) connection of [`user`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) object via [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/):

```
http://graph.facebook.com/me/friends
```

You may specify desired details with `fields` argument (see full list of fields on [`user` object documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/)):

```
http://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?fields=name,picture,birthday
```

You may also subscribe to [Real-time Updates](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/) for `friends` connection of `user` object to get notification on addition/removal of friends so you'll be able to sync changes.

Same functionality can be achieved in [PHP-SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/) with [`Facebook::api`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-api/) method:

```
$config = array(
  'appId' => 'YOUR_APP_ID',
  'secret' => 'YOUR_APP_SECRET',
);

$facebook = new Facebook($config);
$facebook->api('/me/friends', array('fields'=>'name,picture,birthday'));
```

Read the [Documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/), dig into [examples](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/tree/master/examples), read [tutorials](http://developers.facebook.com/search?path&q=tutorial&num=20&DEVSITE_BLOG=0&DEVSITE_DOCS=1&DEVSITE_REFERENCE=0&DEVSITE_Q_AND_A=0&DEVSITE_BUGS=0&DEVSITE_ALL=0) and you'll find what you want.

Comment: The problem I encountered is when I user the permission "user_friends" when login, I ONLY can import the contacts which also grant my app to access.. I also checked the document, it says, "This permission grants the app permission to read a list of this person's friends who also use your app. If any of this person's friends have chosen not to share their list of friends with your app, they will not show up in the list of friends for this person. Both people must have enable the user_friends permission enabled for a friend to show up in either friend list."

Answer (score -1):

[Here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/#login) there is an explanation about how to register and get user data with facebook-sdk.
Once user sign-in you can get user data and store it in your DB.

```
$userId = $facebook->getUser();
$userInfo = $facebook->api('/' + $userId);
$userName = $userInfo['name'];
//store name to db function
```

Comment: This extracts the **current user's** data.  What the OP asked for is the users' **contacts** information - that means the users friends...