# Get those of my facebook friends that are part of a custom list

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I can get the complete list of my friends as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3835568/627517) describes. Is it possible to get just those of my friends that belong to a custom list I've created? I've tried researching this question for a while and am coming up with mixed answers. It looks like I can access "smart lists" which are automatically created by Facebook, but I don't see a way to get the list of friends I've created and filled manually.

Comment: have you tried the facebook opengraph api tool?
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the open graph API tool located at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer, I was able to get my custom user lists including the friends in the lists with querystring below. You need to set extended permission for read_friendlist

```
https://graph.facebook.com/1212121212?fields=id,name,friendlists.list_type(user_created).fields(members,name)
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/FriendList/

You need query for "user_created" list_types

Of course, replace 1212121212 with your user_id